# .htaccess rule for string

Tags: .htaccess

Now I have such rules in htaccess. As you can see it redirects from /sjdfsd to /hello.php?query=sjdfsd
sjdfsd - is a string which can contain 0-9, a-z, &, = and other symbols.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z\&\=\.\[\]\{\}\%\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /hello.php?query=%1 [L]
```

I need to add one more symblol "_", but when I update the second line like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z\&\=\.\[\]\{\}\%\-\_]+)$ [NC]
```

I have an error on the page

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

How I can do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([a-z0-9_[\]{}%&=-]+)$ [NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just simplify your rules to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid file/directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /hello.php?query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This type of test does not use unnecessary time to the server ?

Comment: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` based checks are used in pretty much all WP, Joomla, other CMS websites and some of them are very busy websites. Haven't seen any drastic performance issues due to this. More often than not it is the website code and DB queries that take most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use \ in this case.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/([0-9a-z\&\=\.\[\]\{\}\%\-_]+)$ [NC]
```

I don't know if that can be the error...